# Filter/Remove Blank Form Variables with PHP for Email

Tags: php, ajax, forms, html-email

I have pieced together some PHP code below that creates a nice HTML email from an Ajax form submission, complete with a table. However I would like to remove any blank, non-required variables from being sent so that only the pertinent information is displayed/sent in the email. What do I need to add?

```
<?php
$destination = "handle@domain.com";
$email_from = $_POST['Email'];

$message = "<html>
<body style=\"font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;\">
Hello,<br>
You have recieved an online form submission:<br><br>
<table width='600' border='1' cellspacing='3'>";

//Gather posted variables:
foreach($_POST as $keys => $vars){
$message .= "<tr>
<td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><b>$keys:</b></td> <td><b><font color='red'>$vars</font></b></td>
</tr>";
}
$message = str_replace("_"," ", $message);
$message .= "
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
mail($destination,"Online Form Submission",$message,"From: $email_from\n".
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n");

echo "Thank you for your submission!";
?>
```

Comment: There is an issue with your $headers = ... lines as well. You're running mail() and concatenating the result to those other strings, then assigning all of that to $headers. First create the headers, then do mail();

Comment: Also, if you do not validate that the email address you receive is a valid email address, you are open to SMTP header injection (which means that a malicious individual could highjack your server to send spam). Tutorial on how to validate it: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Comment: Hi Tasos! Thanks for the response. I will look into the email validation. As far as the headers I think I am over my head. What should the entire finished code look like with the corrected headers?

Comment: $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
mail($destination,"Online Form Submission",$message,$headers);

Comment: Thanks Tasos! Appreciate the help!

Comment: Fixed it for you :) Added the validation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things fixed:

- Email validation. (important)
- empty $vars are not printed
- $headers separated properly

Code:

```
//shamelessly stolen from http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if
(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

$destination = "handle@domain.com";
$email_from = $_POST['Email'];

if (!validEmail($email_from))
    die("Invalid email address");

$message = "<html>
<body style=\"font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;\">
Hello,<br>
You have recieved an online form submission:<br><br>
<table width='600' border='1' cellspacing='3'>";

//Gather posted variables:
foreach($_POST as $keys => $vars){
    if (empty($vars)) continue; #skip if vars is empty
    $message .= "<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><b>$keys:</b></td> <td><b><font color='red'>$vars</font></b></td>
    </tr>";
}
$message = str_replace("_"," ", $message);
$message .= "
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

#separating headers properly
$headers = "From: $email_from\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($destination,"Online Form Submission",$message,$headers);

echo "Thank you for your submission!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable is empty, and skip the current iteration if it is:

```
foreach($_POST as $keys => $vars){
    if (empty($vars)) {
        continue;
    }
    $message .= "<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><b>$keys:</b></td> <td><b><font color='red'>$vars</font></b></td>
    </tr>";
 }
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu! Thanks for the response. Where should I put that code?

Comment: @user2364414 Sorry I thought it was clear enough. I added a little more of your code to provide better context. The `if (empty($vars)) ...` should come after the foreach.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! Worked perfectly.